# How to extract metadata from File object in Python Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, metadata

How to extract metadata from File(image) received from form to Django 1.10(python3.5) backend. I am currently using exifread tool. I am successfully able to do read metadata from file saved in the file system.

I am looking for some code like this :

```
imagefile = request.FILES['image']
imagetype = imagefile.content_type.split('/')[1]
metadata = exifread.process_file(imagefile, strict=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to change imagefile to BytesIO object for passing it to exifread.

```
        imagef = base64.b64encode(imagefile.read())
        imagedecoded=base64.b64decode(imagef)
        imagedecoded=BytesIO(imagedecoded)
        metadata = exifread.process_file(imagedecoded)
```

Comment: How to import BytesIO : from io import BytesIO